# Using a DataTable with my app

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm using [Dash](https://dash.plot.ly/live-updates) to build a dashboard with python. I have the following code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_table_experiments as dte
import dash_html_components as html
from datetime import datetime as dt

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id = 'url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id = 'page-content')
])
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

def get_index():
    index = html.Div([
        dcc.Link('Live Data', href='/live')
    ], className = 'row')
    return index

live = html.Div([
    html.H1('Table '),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id = 'selected-period',
            initial_visible_month=dt(2018, 4, 5),
            start_date = dt(2018, 4, 22),
            end_date=dt(2018, 4, 25)
    ),
    # dte.DataTable(
    #     rows= [{}],
    #     row_selectable = True,
    #     filterable = True,
    #     sortable = True,
    #     editable = False,
    #     id = 'data-table'
    # )
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('page-content', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')]
)
def display_correct_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/live':
        return live
    else:
        return get_index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I want to work with the `dash_core_components.Link`, but it seems not compatible with `dash_table_experiments`. When I run this code with the `dte.DataTable` commented out, the app works fine. When I try the run the app with the `dte.DataTable` part, I get a white screen.. I don't understand why this is happening, since I've used `dte.DataTable` before and I had no problems whatsoever. The problem seems to lie in the fact that I'm using `dcc.Link` but I don't understand why it would.

**Question:** Is there a way to use `dte.DataTable` with `dcc.Links`? If so; how can I change my script so that it shows the desired DataTable?

(I understand that I can make this script work by removing the `dcc.Link` part and just running it like a very basic app. I want to be able to use the link because I want to combine two different apps with `dte.DataTable`.)

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dash [expects](https://community.plot.ly/t/display-tables-in-dash/4707/68) that the initial `layout` has all the components present, i.e. you would need to create an empty table in your layout.

If you add a hidden table

```
html.Div(dte.DataTable(rows=[{}]), style={'display': 'none'}),
```

to your `app.layout` it should work.

Comment: Just one more thing! If I now run the script there are two DataTables! How do I hide the one in layout?

Comment: @Mr.President: see updated answer, wrapping the table in a `div` and hiding it via `style` should do it.

Comment: I have only one question left and I think you could easily answer it since you're this good! Could I message you?

Answer (score 1):

Great answer @maximilian. In case this is helpful to anyone, a lot has changed with the Dash DataTable in the last two years, so here's a tutorial I made on the DataTable that helps one get started. https://youtu.be/USTqY4gH_VM